# Plot3D missing a zone

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am trying to plot a simple graph using `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[0.25*(1/(1 - 0.9* (1 - bn))) ((1 - bn)/(1 - 0.5* bn))^2, {bn, 0, 1}, {bu, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{bn, bu}, bn > bu]]
```

Which gives the output:

[image]

Why is there a triangle where `Plot3D` keeps the function flat while it is clearly increasing. Here is the graph without limit on the region:

[image]

I also tried different approaches. For instance:

```
Plot3D[0.25*(1/(1 - 0.9* (1 - bn))) ((1 - bn)/(1 - 0.5* bn))^2*If[bn > bu, 1, 0], 
  {bn, 0,1}, {bu, 0, 1}]
```

with even worst outcome:

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `ClippingStyle -> None` will remove the "triangle" and the answer below overcomes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *Mathematica* automatically determines the plot range, it sometimes decides to clip off the very high or very low parts of the graph.  It does this, I suppose, when including the extreme parts of the range results in a plot that is flattened too much.  If you don't want this, *Mathematica* also supplies easy options to override the automatic behavior.

Try `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Plot3D[0.25*(1/(1 - 0.9*(1 - bn))) ((1 - bn)/(1 - 0.5*bn))^2,
 {bn, 0, 1}, {bu, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{bn, bu}, bn > bu], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Only a small part of the graph above sticks up high.  With the setting `PlotRange -> Automatic`, *Mathematica* decides to chop part of it off.  Without the restriction by `RegionFunction`, as in the OP's second plot, the high part runs along the whole `bu` axis.  In that case, *Mathematica* doesn't cut it off.   If it were steeper it would cut it off:

```
Plot3D[0.25*(1/(1 - 0.95*(1 - bn))) ((1 - bn)/(1 - 0.5*bn))^2,
 {bn, 0,1}, {bu, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! Any idea what the problem is with the other methods?

Comment: @mathtd  See edit.  I think that's what you were asking about.  I don't know what the exact algorithm is for clipping.